# Technical vs non-technical questions and answers

Tags: discussion

Re: [How does Sitecore "match" a pattern card for personalization?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/55/how-does-sitecore-match-a-pattern-card-for-personalization/68#68)

I posted this question as an example of something a marketer might post. Adam knows who I am, so that maybe affected his answer, but I don't think many marketers will know what Euclidean distance is. :) Is there some way we can tag or flag posts to indicate that the user is looking for a non-technical / "ELI5" answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is follow up with a comment on the answer asking them to clarify with more details. I have no idea what Euclidean distance is either... but there is no reason that;

- you have to accept the answer
- you have to upvote the answer. Downvote if you think it is wrong
- somebody else can provide an answer
- you can provide your own answer, expanding on any of the other answers already provided if you feel they are insufficient

Comment: Yeah I suppose a tag might be overkill. Just trying to avoid frustration for non-technical folk.

Comment: I agree with this. Ultimately, the question asker will have to make the decision on whether or not an answer provides the right amount of ELI5-ness or not.  If they don't understand a response, they can make a comment about it, and the user that answered can change their answer to accomodate much like Adam Conn did.